# IGListKit section item with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

I am implementing `IGListKit` and in my section, **one** of my item has dynamic height.

I followed the example project "SelfSizingCells" on IGListKit repo, but when I try to reproduce it, my app infinite loops on :

```
"the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values"
```

After making sure I set `estimatedSize` on the `UICollectionView` layout, and I override `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` in my cell, I realized that the code works only if I load one item in my section, and not the others items coming above... So, if my dynamic-height item is alone in the section, it works.

Now, I ask myself if I can mix my non-dynamic-height items with dynamic-height items, since in the IGListKit example only displays sections of the same item.

Note: In my section controller `sizeForItem` returns always the same static size...